# gnome-terminal starts with "grep: write error: Broken pipe" message

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, bashrc

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.3, it's uptodate. I don't know why, for a few days I began to take `grep: write error: Broken pipe` message on launching **gnome-terminal** . It seems to be harmless but it bothers me. How  can I debug it?

EDIT: I moved aliases and functions each to separate files such as `.bash_aliases` and `.bash_functions` and added a command to load them from `.bashrc`

```
 if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
. ~/.bash_aliases
 fi

 if [ -f ~/.bash_functions ]; then
. ~/.bash_functions
 fi
```

If I  don't load `.bash_functions` problem disappears.

I am trying to find the faulty one by disabling each function one by one.

This one gives me the same error but when I disable it I keep getting the same error, so I may have more faulty functions.

```
 ls -lt  $PWD| grep ^d | head -1 | cut -b 51- 

 grep:  development
 write error: Broken pipe
```

I wonder why I begin to take that error.

EDIT2:

I found a similar problem here [boken pipe](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2007-11/msg00078.html)

The root of the problem also seems similar.

I tried the given test command in the link which have the same error:

```
 bash -c '(while echo foo; do :; done); echo status=$? >&2' |  head
 foo
 foo
 foo
 foo
 foo
 foo
 foo
 foo
 foo
 foo
 bash: line 0: echo: write error: Broken pipe
 status=0
```

EDIT3:

Though that `unbuffer` workaround I posted below as an answer to my own question  works, I am not satisfied with it, but my knowledge about debugging is limited. Acoording to this link https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2007-11/msg00080.html it stems from SIGPIPE trap by another task,  and this link  https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2007-11/msg00154.html  pinpoints the exact cause of the problem, it's one of the pam authentication module which I am in trouble with it recently.

Comment: Look for `grep` in your `.bashrc`, `.profile`, etc. And is it only in gnome-terminal? Not in xterm, or in the TTYs?

Comment: @muru I already checked `.bashrc` and `.profile` I haven't added any new functions recently. I have a number of grep and  | (pipe) in functions in them but they are there for months.

Comment: @muru
when I run your command `shopt -s nullglob; ls -t */ | head -1` I get `development/:
ls: write error: Broken pipe` output

Comment: @muru I posted output of `ls -dt */ ` in `development` directory. Added it to my question.

Comment: I meant, I wanted the output of `printf '%q' */` in whichever directory you were originally in, and that I meant the replacement function would be: `shopt -s nullglob; ls -dt */ | head -1`. Sorry for the miscommunication.

Comment: @muru `shopt -s nullglob; ls -dt */ | head -1` just runs fine and gives `development/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of struggling with the problem I found a working workaround (I hope so)

Problem seems to be deeper and complicated. Many people met the same bug. Fixing it is beyond my coverage.

Closest workaround posted here [how-can-i-fix-a-broken-pipe-error](https://superuser.com/questions/554855/how-can-i-fix-a-broken-pipe-error) by Andrew Beals at bottom like :

```
ls -lt $PWD|dd obs=1M | grep -m 1 ^d | cut -b 51-
```

is not neat.

When I intuited that it's related to pipe buffer I gave a shot to `unbuffer` command like :

```
 unbuffer ls -lt $PWD| grep -m 1 ^d | cut -b 51-
```

It works well.

I hope somebody posts the real cause of the problem.

EDIT: A bash Guru would suggest this simple solution , redirecting stderr to `/dev/null`

```
 ls -lt $PWD 2>/dev/null | grep -m 1 ^d | cut -b 51-
```

Comment: Killing stderr's output hides other error conditions from you.  When working with large output today, I found that I had to increase the buffer size in dd again and though about the problem a little more.  In the strictest sense, the pipe is "broken", but the shell shoudn't be telling the user about it and for the simple case of excess data, but not too much excess data as it's all sitting in buffers, SIGPIPE does not happen: cat /etc/passwd | grep -m1 ssh

For "Big Data" problems here such as your example, I would change it to `ls -lt $PWD | (grep -m 1 ^d ; dd of=/dev/null) | cut -b 51-`

Comment: Yes, this takes longer, but avoids having to do janky things such as redirecting stderr to /dev/null in the script.  However, it's a bad solution in and of itself, as it's preventing the upstream command from exiting after you're done consuming its data.

More discussion here: http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/sigpipe_handling.html

Comment: @AndrewBeals Thank you for further info and suggestion. Beside the point do you think Gnome developers are programmers or self-satisfying obfuscators?

Answer (score 5):

There's a great explanation of this problem on this Super User answer: [How can I fix a Broken Pipe error?](https://superuser.com/a/554896/427197).

Commands in pipes are run asynchronously: this means that in a pipe such as `command1 | command2` there's no guarantee that `command1` will end before `command2`.

When using `[...] | grep | head -n 1`, `head` ends as soon as it has read one line; if this happens before `grep` has finished writing to the pipe, `grep` receives a SIGPIPE signal and errors out.

As explained in the answer below that Super User answer, a workaround is to pipe the output of what's before `head` in the pipeline to `tail -n +1` first, which will ignore the SIGPIPE signal:

```
command | tail -n +1 | head -n 1
```

But in this case there's not even any need for `head`, since `grep` has an option to print only the first match:

```
[...] | grep -m 1
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. How can I apply it to my particular case for `ls -lt  $PWD| grep ^d | head -1 | cut -b 51- ` and generalize it?

Comment: @kenn I had a misconception about pipes and the answer wasn't technically accurate before, it should be now. Also see the update, there's no real need for `grep | head`.

Comment: @kenn Meaning: `ls -lt $PWD| grep -m 1 ^d | cut -b 51-`.

Comment: `ls -lt $PWD| grep -m 1 ^d | cut -b 51-` still gives me the same error `development
ls: write error: Broken pipe` :(

Comment: @kenn Looks like the same is happening with `cut` as well. What about `ls -lt $PWD| grep ^d | tail -n +1 | head -n 1 | cut -b 51-`?

Comment: hey, it works :) how?

Comment: Sorry, I spoke too early, it fails

Comment: Sometimes it just runs well but it often fails

Comment: @kenn Ah but the last error was from `ls`. Just for testing, try this: `ls -lt $PWD| tail -n +1 | grep -m 1 ^d | cut -b 51-`.

Comment: Right, I noticed that just after I posted the output. Above code gives me `development
tail: write error: Broken pipe
tail: write error
`

Comment: @kenn I'm starting to think that in this case the problem is with Bash or `grep`. Version of both?

Comment: `GNU bash, version 4.3.11` and  `grep (GNU grep) 2.16`

Comment: @kenn Sorry, also the output of `md5sum /bin/bash` and `md5sum /bin/grep`, to check if one of the two is corrupted... Though a corruption normally causes way worse problems.

Comment: you are the master and I need your help. `9c96f6ac51aaf5deb8043d8c2330da69  /bin/bash`   and `b0ce14813cf497a45c894d73fa309ba8  /bin/grep`

Comment: @kenn Could you also provide the version of the related packages? You can check them with `apt-cache policy bash` / `apt-cache policy grep` (again, the corruption thing is a long shot, but just to be sure).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35744/discussion-between-kos-and-kenn).